# Java BufferWriter not completing write of file

Tags: java, xml

Here is my situation. I am writing `<!ENTITY>` declarations to an XML file. I read in the original XML file using a Scanner. As the scanner reads the input file i write the lines out to the BufferedWriter. When the scanner is on line 2 i write my `<!ENTITY>` values from an ArrayList that was passed to the method. My `<!ENTITY>` values write no problem. Issue I am having is that I am only getting 400 or so lines of the file written to the output file.

[image]

I've read through a few posts on here regarding BufferedWriters not completing writes to files, and all seemed to point to ensuring the writer is closed. I have closed my writer object.

```
private void addEntityRefs(Map<String, String> icns, File xml)
{
    String path = xml.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,xml.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(File.separator)+1);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner reader = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> e : icns.entrySet())
    {
       list.add(e.getValue());
    }
    try
    {
        reader = new Scanner(xml);
        //standardOut.println("Reading " + xml.getName());
        //System.out.println();
        int c = 0;
        String output = path + "out2.xml";
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(output)));

        while(reader.hasNextLine())
        {
            c++;
            if(c == 1)
            {
                writer.append(reader.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s", " "));
            }
            else if(c == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("writing entities @ line 2");
                writer.append("\n<!DOCTYPE pm [\n");

                for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
                {
                    writer.append("<!ENTITY " + list.get(i).trim() + " SYSTEM \"" + list.get(i).trim() + ".cgm\" NDATA cgm>\n");
                }
                writer.append("<!NOTATION cgm PUBLIC \"cgm\" \"\">\n]>\n");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Writing line " + c);
                writer.append(reader.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s", " ")+ "\r");
            }

        }

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(AARPdfGenUI.class.getName()).log(Level.WARN, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex, "File Not Found Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(AARPdfGenUI.class.getName()).log(Level.WARN, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex, "IO Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(AARPdfGenUI.class.getName()).log(Level.WARN, null, e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e, "Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the writer is used to generate PDFs. The file being read and `<!ENTITY>` declarations added to is about 26,000 lines long. Can someone point me to where I have gone wrong? This method works without issue when I run the application from NetBeans, but once I build it and attempt to run from the JAR file is when it stops after about 400 lines.

Comment: Are you getting any relevant log messages?  Do you know if the `while` loop terminates normally or with an exception?

Comment: @StephenC no, there are no log messages. I am lost as to how it runs fine in the IDE, but when built it will not complete the write.

Comment: You didn't answer the second question.

Comment: I did not, my mistake. No there was no exception from the while loop. The exception came in a follow on method that was processing the resultant XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it stops at certain line. do you see the file getting created with those lines? could be that buffer is been flushed at that moment and failed in that operation.

You does not move the pointer to the next line when c == 2 but continue to write in in next iteration.
It is always better to use the charset when reading/writing.
try flushing at the end.
and closing both reader and writer in-dependently.
needless use of ArrayList.

i did minor changes to this one. see if it still works.

```
private void addEntityRefs(Map<String, String> icns, File xml) {
    Scanner reader = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        reader = new Scanner(xml, "utf-8");
        // standardOut.println("Reading " + xml.getName());
        // System.out.println();
        int count = 0;
        File targetFile = new File(xml.getParentFile(), "out2.xml");
        if (!targetFile.exists()) {
            boolean created = targetFile.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("File created: " + created);
        }
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(targetFile));

        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            count++;
            if (count == 1) {
                writer.append(reader.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s", " "));
            } else if (count == 2) {
                System.out.println("writing entities @ line 2");
                writer.append("\n<!DOCTYPE pm [\n");

                for (String item : icns.keySet()) {
                    item = item.trim();
                    writer.append("<!ENTITY " + item + " SYSTEM \"" + item + ".cgm\" NDATA cgm>\n");
                }
                writer.append("<!NOTATION cgm PUBLIC \"cgm\" \"\">\n]>\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Writing line " + count);
                writer.append(reader.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s", " ")).append("\r");
            }
        }
        // done writing
        writer.flush();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AARPdfGenUI.class.getName()).log(Level.WARN, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex, "File Not Found Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AARPdfGenUI.class.getName()).log(Level.WARN, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex, "IO Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(AARPdfGenUI.class.getName()).log(Level.WARN, null, e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e, "Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(AARPdfGenUI.class.getName()).log(Level.WARN, null, e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e, "Exception", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This processed the file. Thank you. I found that the encoding is required in the Scanner, as if I remove it, the file fails at the same point.